# Background image not displaying

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-assets

So while modifying an existing framework, I am trying to change the background image. Not only have I deleted the image from the Assets folder, I am calling the new background image. But for some reason the old background is what shows up

This is where the image is being loaded.

```
      public static void load() {
            icLauncher = loadBitmap("ic_launcher_36",false);
       dodgingfire_welcome = loadBitmap("dodgingfire_welcome.png", false);
            block = loadBitmap("block.png", false);
            cloud1 = loadBitmap("cloud1.png", true);
            cloud2 = loadBitmap("cloud2.png", true);
            duck = loadBitmap("duck.png", true);
            grass = loadBitmap("grass.png", false);
```

This is where the method is being called.

```
     @Override
        public void render(Painter g) {
    g.drawImage(Assets.dodgingfire_welcome, 0, 0);
            startButton.render(g);
           scoreButton.render(g);
        }
```

These are the full classes

```
package rect.draw.gametest.model.state;

import android.view.MotionEvent;

import rect.draw.gametest.Assets;
import rect.draw.gametest.model.util.Painter;
import rect.draw.gametest.model.util.UIButton;


public class MenuState extends State {
    private UIButton startButton, scoreButton;

    @Override
    public void init() {
        startButton = new UIButton(316, 227, 484, 286, Assets.start,
                Assets.startDown);
        scoreButton = new UIButton(316, 300, 484, 359, Assets.score,
                Assets.scoreDown);
    }

    @Override
    public void update(float delta) {
    }

    @Override
    public void render(Painter g) {

        g.drawImage(Assets.dodgingfire_welcome, 0, 0);
        startButton.render(g);
       scoreButton.render(g);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(MotionEvent e, int scaledX, int scaledY) {
        if (e.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            startButton.onTouchDown(scaledX, scaledY);
            scoreButton.onTouchDown(scaledX, scaledY);
        }
        if (e.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
            if (startButton.isPressed(scaledX, scaledY)) {
                startButton.cancel();
                setCurrentState(new PlayState());
            } else if (scoreButton.isPressed(scaledX, scaledY)) {
                scoreButton.cancel();
                setCurrentState(new ScoreState());
            } else {
                startButton.cancel();
                scoreButton.cancel();
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

2nd class

```
package rect.draw.gametest;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Bitmap.Config;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory.Options;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.media.SoundPool;



public class Assets {
    private static SoundPool soundPool;
    public static Bitmap dodgingfire_welcome, block, cloud1, cloud2, duck, grass, jump,
            run1, run2, run3, run4, run5, scoreDown, score, startDown, start, icLauncher,iceCream1,iceCream2,iceCream3,fire,mountains;



   // public static Animation runAnim, aba;
    public static int hitID, onJumpID;


    public static void load() {
        icLauncher = loadBitmap("ic_launcher_36",false);
        dodgingfire_welcome = loadBitmap("dodgingfire_welcome.png", false);
        block = loadBitmap("block.png", false);
        cloud1 = loadBitmap("cloud1.png", true);
        cloud2 = loadBitmap("cloud2.png", true);
        duck = loadBitmap("duck.png", true);
        grass = loadBitmap("grass.png", false);
        jump = loadBitmap("jump.png", true);
        run1 = loadBitmap("run_anim1.png", true);
        run2 = loadBitmap("run_anim2.png", true);
        run3 = loadBitmap("run_anim3.png", true);
        run4 = loadBitmap("run_anim4.png", true);
        run5 = loadBitmap("run_anim5.png", true);
        scoreDown = loadBitmap("score_button_down.png", true);
        score = loadBitmap("score_button.png", true);
        startDown = loadBitmap("start_button_down.png", true);
        start = loadBitmap("start_button.png", true);
        mountains=loadBitmap("mountains.png",true);

        iceCream1 = loadBitmap("ice_cream1.png",true);
        iceCream2=loadBitmap("ice_cream2.png",true);
        iceCream3=loadBitmap("ice_cream3.png",true);

        fire=loadBitmap("fire.png",true);

   //     Frame f1 = new Frame(run1, .1f);
   //     Frame f2 = new Frame(run2, .1f);
   //     Frame f3 = new Frame(run3, .1f);
    //    Frame f4 = new Frame(run4, .1f);
    //    Frame f5 = new Frame(run5, .1f);

    //    runAnim = new Animation(f1, f2, f3, f4, f5, f3, f2);
        hitID = loadSound("hit.wav");
        onJumpID = loadSound("onjump.wav");
    }

    private static Bitmap loadBitmap(String filename, boolean transparency) {
        InputStream inputStream = null;
        try {
            inputStream = GameMainActivity.assets.open(filename);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Options options = new Options();
        if (transparency) {
            options.inPreferredConfig = Config.ARGB_8888;
        } else {
            options.inPreferredConfig = Config.RGB_565;
        }
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream, null,
                options);
        return bitmap;
    }

    private static int loadSound(String filename) {
        int soundID = 0;
        if (soundPool == null) {
            soundPool = new SoundPool(25, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);
        }
        try {
            soundID = soundPool.load(GameMainActivity.assets.openFd(filename),
                    1);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return soundID;
    }

    public static void playSound(int soundID) {
        soundPool.play(soundID, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Rebuild the project. Images are not cleaned up when building/saving. You need to delete the current build.